# How to exclude from project stax-utils dependency for tagsoup?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm running Debian Wheezy, openjdk-7-jre, clojure 1.4.0 and leiningen-1.7.1, all installed from official repo.

I have a project.clj like this:

```
(defproject guess-film "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME"
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"],
    [clj-http "0.5.0"],
    [clj-tagsoup "0.3.0" :exclusions [net.java.dev.stax-utils/stax-utils]]
  ]
  :main guess-film.core
)
```

As you can see on that stage I excluded stax-utils, actually this is described on clj-tagsoup Github page.

Then I have this src/guess-film/core.clj:

```
ns guess-film.core
    (:require
        [clj-http.client :as client]
        [pl.danieljanus.tagsoup :as parser :refer [parse parse-string]] :verbose
    )
)
```

And when I try to

```
lein repl
```

it crashes, I presume because of unsatisfied stax-utils:

```
...
(clojure.core/load "/pl/danieljanus/tagsoup")
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/zip")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'pl.danieljanus.tagsoup)
(clojure.core/alias 'zip 'clojure.zip)
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/xml")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'pl.danieljanus.tagsoup)
(clojure.core/alias 'xml 'clojure.xml)
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/data/xml")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.data.xml)
(clojure.core/alias 'str 'clojure.string)
(clojure.core/in-ns 'pl.danieljanus.tagsoup)
(clojure.core/alias 'lazy-xml 'clojure.data.xml)
ClassNotFoundException javanet.staxutils.ContentHandlerToXMLEventWriter  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

I tried to evade loading of lazy-xml by using :refer, but that doesn't work I presume. Also I tried ":use ... :only [parse parse-string]" with no success either.

I just don't like to load what I am not going to use :)

Is it clj-tagsoup failure that it tries to load lazy-xml anyway?
If I can't escape from that dependency, will it be a perfomance hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clj-tagsoup the one that is importing the javanet.staxutils.Content... class, so I don't think there is much that you can do about it.

It won't be any performance hit, loading just another class it is not going to make much of a difference and it is not going to use much memory either.